# Swift-4: Can't move to another ViewController from a ViewController

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, swift4.1

I have designed a UITableviewCell using Xib. The cell has a button when the button clicked it should move to another viewController. I have written delegate method to trigger the function in viewController, in the function, I used PushViewController but It has not moved to another ViewController so how to resolve it?. Also, I have included UINavigationController as RootViewController by Embaded in the project. The following method is triggered by the button when clicked.

```
func showMoreAboutLeads(index: IndexPath)
{
    print("Show_More_About_Leads:",index)

    let detailController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsLeadController") as! DetailsLeadController
    detailController.leadsDetail = self.leadsArray[index.row] as! NSDictionary
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Is this func getting triggered or not? Means, is this print stmt called?

Answer (score 0):

if the function is called when clicked, you must make sure that the page has a navigation bar or not.
otherwise you will not be able to push the page but must present the page

**self.present(detailController, animated: true, completion: nil)**